# Change FrameLayout dynamically in a BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-framelayout

So, my problem is this, I want change the layout when a different button is clicked in the bottom bar. 
I want to show different widget when each button is clicked. 
My activity_main.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.codanimex.android.prova.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_home" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java is:

```
package com.codanimex.android.prova;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

If I have to use fragments, can you explain it? I could not understand their functioning. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create Fragment for each button, with its own layout
For Example: `HomeFragment`, `DashboardFragment`, `NotificationFragment`.

then remove the TextView from inside the FrameLayout, as it's not required anymore, since you are going to show the fragment itself. activity_main.xml will be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.codanimex.android.prova.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then Update the code in MainActivity.java to switch between fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private enum NavigationFragment{
        Home,
        Dashboard,
        Notification
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    ChangeFragment(NavigationFragment.Home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    ChangeFragment(NavigationFragment.Dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    ChangeFragment(NavigationFragment.Notification);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    private void ChangeFragment(NavigationFragment value){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (value) {
            case Home:    fragment = new HomeFragment(); break;
            case Dashboard: fragment = new DashboardFragment(); break;
            case Notification: fragment= new NotificationFragment();break;
         }
        if(fragment!=null)
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, fragment)
                    .commit();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

Comment: if you are trying only to replace a static content with another static content that don't have any action, then you should consider replacing the concept of Fragment with normal replacement of view `frameLayout.removeAllViews(); frameLayout.addView(view);`